# SGBD para SQLite

Tags: android, banco-de-dados, sqlite, sqlite3

Alguém pode me recomendar um bom SGBD SQLite, pois estou usando o **sqlitebrowser** para gerenciar os bancos de dados das minhas aplicações Android, porém não consigo fazer quase nada nele.

Comment: A pergunta pode não estar muito bem formulada. Mas no que diz respeito as respostas até dão um certo jeito para saber ferramentas para sqlite. Que tal editar a pergunta e esmiuçar mais o que precisa realmente?

Answer (score 5):

Acho que na verdade você esta querendo um gerenciador de Banco de dados, tal como o MySQL Workbench é para bancos de dados MySQL. 
Para SQLite eu já usei **SQLiteExpert** http://www.sqliteexpert.com e o **SQLiteMan** - http://sqliteman.com para gerenciar e debug de um projeto. Com elas é possível criar o banco, manipular as tabelas dentro e fora do emulador ou PDA. Quando realizado fora do emulador ele gera um arquivo que pode facilmente ser importado.

Answer (score 4):

Acho que você quer um *Database Manager* para SQLite?

Se for o caso eu uso e recomendo o [SQLiteStudio](http://sqlitestudio.pl/), não utilizo nada incrivelmente avançado em relação a base de dados SQLite, mais ele sempre me atendeu completamente.

E uso [esse](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/04/18/sqlitemanager-plugin-for-eclipse/) somente para consultar a base de dados pelo eclipse, no caso do emulador, ou do dispositivo ser *root*, é muito útil, pois não preciso ficar baixando a base de dados para a maquina para abri-la.

Answer (score 1):

Utilizo o SQLite Administration (http://sqliteadmin.orbmu2k.de/). Uma ferramenta executável (sem precisar instalar) e simples de usar. Se tratando de um BD simples a ferramenta ajuda muito.